# VBA web scraping update

Tags: html, vba, web, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I have following code it:

1. open a webpage (amazon in this case)
2. click on all the products appearing on the page ( and open each product in new tab)
3. go through each open tab (from step 2), copy the "product title" and paste it to column A

Can you help me to update the code to include a loop:

4. which go through each open tab (from step 2) and copy the price element and paste it in column B corresponding to product title

The HTML element is for the price is "649"

```
Sub launch_product()
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim doc_ele As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim doc_eles As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

Dim startoftitle As Integer, endoftitle As Integer, rownum As Long
Dim vouterHTML As String, ProductTitle As String

Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.amazon.in/s?k=rudra+fashion&rh=p_n_size_two_browse-vebin%3A1975333031&dc&crid=2AKWK100N33Q9&qid=1574534623&rnid=1974754031&sprefix=rudra+fas%2Caps%2C287&ref=sr_nr_p_n_size_two_browse-vebin_8"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
   Application.StatusBar = "Loading"
Loop
Set idoc = IE.Document

Set doc_eles = idoc.getElementsByTagName("img")
rownum = 1

For Each doc_ele In doc_eles
    If doc_ele.className = "s-image" Then
       doc_ele.Click

       vouterHTML = doc_ele.outerHTML
       startoftitle = InStr(1, vouterHTML, "alt=") + 5
       endoftitle = InStr(startoftitle, vouterHTML, """") - 1
       ProductTitle = Mid(vouterHTML, startoftitle, endoftitle - startoftitle + 1)
       ActiveSheet.Cells(rownum, 1).Value = ProductTitle
       rownum = rownum + 1
    End If
Next doc_ele

ActiveSheet.Columns(1).EntireColumn.AutoFit
IE.Quit
```

End Sub

Comment: why are you going to different pages and in different tabs? Isn't all the info on the one page?

Comment: It is on one page, if you can help me get it. I was going through each page as intended to get more info from each page but for the time being scraping info from one page will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would grab the titles from alt attribute of nodes matched by class and price, assuming you want current, from one of two class name match nodes. You don't need a browser as content is present in response from a simple xmlhttp request which is faster.

As Rupee symbol is not present for all price nodes I remove it where present.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteOutProductInfo()
    'VBE>Tools>References> Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.amazon.in/s?k=kuki+fashion&rh=p_72%3A1318476031&dc&qid=1574617862&rnid=1318475031&ref=sr_nr_p_72_1", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim headers(), titles As Object, prices As Object
    headers = Array("Title", "Price", "Img url")

    With html
        Set titles = .querySelectorAll(".s-image")
        Set prices = .querySelectorAll(".a-price-whole,.a-color-price")
    End With

    Dim results(), r As Long, priceInfo As String

    ReDim results(1 To titles.Length, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

    For r = 0 To titles.Length - 1
        results(r + 1, 1) = titles.Item(r).alt
        results(r + 1, 2) = Replace$(prices.Item(r).innerText, ChrW(8377), vbNullString)
        results(r + 1, 3) = titles.Item(r).src
    Next

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: is this what you were after?

Comment: can you help with my comment please !

Comment: I will have a look later but bear in mind you can necessarily just transfer code across urls.

Comment: understood. In this case it is same type of product at amazon. Just the seller name has been changed

Comment: It works for me though weirdly it returns some additional results not on the visible page.

Comment: Redim one. Thanks. I figured it out. Error is because I have more than one workbooks open and code is confused which Sheet1 to go I believe.   Is it possible you can add url for the image as well in column C?

Comment: You are a STAR !

Comment: QHarr can you help me if you can. One in 4 times I encounter the "Run time 9 error"  at the following line of the code:   ReDim results(1 To titles.Length, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

Comment: 1/4 with same url?

Comment: with different url

Comment: You may need to open a new questions with all the details you please. Make sure we can reproduce the problem.